# spark streaming wordcount is not printing the results

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to run this app in spark streaming the code is from a book I am reading but unfortunately I am not getting the expected results. There is a java class in which I open a socket and wait for an input. I run the socket code and connect it properly with the spark job. Then I submit the following job and I get a message that I connected successfully. When I type something in the socket I want to get a wordcount result printed in the terminal instead I am getting this message:

> INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added input-0-1480077969600 in memory on 192.168.1.4:38818 (size: 7.0 B, free: 265.1 MB)

where is the problem? See the code bellow, thanks in advance

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream

object ScalaFirstStreamingExample {
def main(args: Array[String]){


println("Creating Spark Configuration") //Create an Object of Spark Configuration
val conf = new SparkConf()  //Set the logical and user defined Name of this Application
conf.setAppName("My First Spark Streaming Application") 
println("Retreiving Streaming Context from Spark Conf") //Retrieving Streaming Context from SparkConf Object.
                                                    //Second parameter is the time interval at which 
                                                    //streaming data will be divided into batches
val streamCtx = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(2))  //Define the type of Stream. Here we are using TCP 
                                                    //Socket as textstream,
                                                    //It will keep watching for the incoming data from a 
                                                    //specific machine (localhost) and port (9087)
                                                    //Once the data is retrieved it will be saved in the 
                                                    //memory and in case memory
                                                    //is not sufficient, then it will store it on the Disk
                                                    //It will further read the Data and convert it into DStream

val lines = streamCtx.socketTextStream("localhost", 9087, MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2) //Apply the Split() function to all elements of DStream
                                                                            //which will further generate multiple new records from 
                                                                            //each record in Source Stream
                                                                            //And then use flatmap to consolidate all records and 
                                                                            //create a new DStream.

val words = lines.flatMap(x => x.split(" "))            //Now, we will count these words by applying a using map()
                                                    //map() helps in applying a given function to each 
                                                    //element in an RDD.
val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))                //Further we will aggregate the value of each key by
                                                    //using/applying the given function.
val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)               //Lastly we will print all Values
                                                    //wordCounts.print(20)

myPrint(wordCounts,streamCtx)       
//Most important statement which will initiate the 
//Streaming Context
streamCtx.start();

//Wait till the execution is completed.

streamCtx.awaitTermination();
}

    def myPrint(stream:DStream[(String,Int)],streamCtx: StreamingContext){
    stream.foreachRDD(foreachFunc)

    def foreachFunc = (rdd: RDD[(String,Int)]) => {
        val array = rdd.collect()
        println("---------Start Printing Results----------")
       for(res<-array){
        println(res)
        }
        println("---------Finished Printing Results----------")
    }
}



}
```

Comment: Are you checking it on executor nodes?

Comment: I am checking the terminal that I submited the job

Comment: What is the spark submit command that you are using

Comment: $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class ScalaFirstStreamingExample --master spark://LOCALHOST:7077 $SPARK_HOME/test_1/target/scala-2.10/firstexample_2.10-1.0.jar

Comment: So it won't be printed on console. Search in worker logs or - better - use logger instead of println

Comment: can you show me how because I am new to this?

Comment: Could you please try `wordCounts.print()`?

Comment: i am getting the same result